# Dynamically updating the urlTemplate property of a MapView.UrlTile component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to React and React Native. I'm using React Native Maps, and trying to dynamically update the `urlTemplate` property of a `MapView.UrlTile` component every second (up to a certain limit).

I attempt to do this by using `setInterval()` to update a state variable. Below is an example of how I'm trying to do this.

```
class App extends React.Component {

    // initial state
    state = {
        url: ""
    };

    // call updateUrl 
    componentWillMount() {
        this.updateUrl();
    }

    // update the url every second 10 times
    updateUrl = () => {
        setInterval(() => {
            for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                this.setState({url: `https://example.com/${i}.png`});
            }
        });
    }

    // render the map
    render () {
        let url = this.state.url;

         return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <MapView
                        style={styles.map}
                        region={region}
                        customMapStyle={mapStyle}
                    >
                        <MapView.UrlTile
                            urlTemplate={url}
                            maximumZ={19}
                            flipY={false}
                        />
                    </MapView>
                </View>
            );
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, the tile image does not seem to change. I expect to see the image on the map change every second or so. If I use an `Image` component, and set the `source` to the `url` property, the image updates every second, as expected. But when using `UrlTile`, the image on the map doesn't seem to update.

The above is a contrived example. In reality, I am working on a weather radar app. When the app launches, I get an array of timestamps of the 10 most recent radar scans that I can then use to build the `urlTemplate` for the tiles. If the app is in "loop" mode, I need to show a different tile every second (or so). The actual URLs I'm passing in are valid (I can bring up the images in the browser, or load them in an `Image` component). But the `UrlTile` component in the map doesn't appear to update.

Any suggestions or thoughts where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by setting a value for `this.state.url` before `setInterval`. For example, if using the example code above:

```
updateUrl = () => {
    this.setState({url: `https://example.com/0.png`});
    setInterval(() => {
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            this.setState({url: `https://example.com/${i}.png`});
        }
    });
}
```